# Google Sheets Concatenating Cells in the Labels When it Should not

Tags: google-sheets

I cannot explain this behaviour. Here is a demo sheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14YQL_nD2L9B1vTh4BgEQHGAcEkaxinjKfSgmHNSwpz0/edit?usp=sharing

here is a function:

=query(A1:B3,"select *")

In a1:b3 I have some very simple data. All strings except one integer. The query function for some reason is concatenating data from each column at the top. If I change the integer to text, the problem resolves

[image: demo query]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=query(A1:B3,"select *",0)
```

- *set the third parameter `[headers]` to `0` to tell query there's no headers in that range; set as `1` to attribute first row as headers*
- as per [query documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343): *If omitted or set to -1, the value
  is guessed based on the content of data*

Comment: This seemed to be the right answer but the query data is also truncated. I added some more rows to columns A and B so you could see those rows just don't show up in the query

Comment: you set a *restricted* range of `A1:B3` within your query function. `change the range` to pick up the new data added from A4 to downside

Comment: thanks you are right but something is still not ok. check the extra sheet I made called demo2. See how the data which should be in columns is moved to the labels and is no longer in rows where it should be.

Your fix  to set header to 0 works, but this is definitely incorrect behaviour

Comment: query does not react well with mixed data-types (having text-type and numericals in the same column per se.,). just replace that single instance of `$5` with `a` and you should see what I am referring to! [this article here](https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/mixed-data-type-issue-in-query/) should be helpful on how to workaround with it. you could also look into [filter function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197) which has no issues whatsoever with this mixed-data-type-thing.

Comment: Well you worked hard for me and you deserve the award of correct answer. Thanks so much for your help

Comment: Just a footnote: It works with mixed data types if you set header to 0

Comment: ***It works with mixed data types if you set header to 0*** Yes for your limited sample dataset but eventually as you expand, you would get to see those miscellaneous data missing errors